# How to use Npgsql - NpgsqlConnection with IP address with an external port

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I am using Npgsql to connect to my PostgreSQL database.
When I use a local address like this:

Login = "Server = 10.0.0.5; Port = 5432; User Id = postgres; Password = Pas123456; Database = mybase; CommandTimeout = 100;

idel works.

When I want to reach the base via an external IP address (73.63.27.130) with NAT port redirection (20400) as below

Login = "Server = 73.63.27.130:20400; Port = 5432; User Id = postgres; Password = Pas123456; Database = mybase; CommandTimeout = 100;

Unfortunately it doesn't work.

It is absolutely certain that port redirection etc. is done correctly, because I use the same datebase in another app on Android with the same parameters works properly.

I think the problem is in the format of writing an IP address with an external port

Answer (score 2):

I think, your connectionstring is wrong. This looks good to me:

`"Server = 73.63.27.130; Port = 20400; User Id = postgres; Password = Pas123456; Database = mybase; CommandTimeout = 100;"`